# If I use letters selecting rows from a SQlite database is not working, why?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-edittext

I have a SQlite database with some columns and with a content of an EditText I would like to select some rows from the database.

In main activity:

case R.id.betx:

```
        String dates2 = sqletx.getText().toString();
        GlobalVars.settables(dates2);
        Intent intentstar2t = new Intent(dbhelp.this, CustomList.class);
            startActivity(intentstar2t);
        break;
```

This is my main activity, the 'dates2' String is the content of the edittext, and I save it for the setTables method.

My code in the hornot class where:

```
 public Cursor getTable() {         
 String deda = GlobalVars.gettables();
 String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS,
 KEY_CALORIE, KEY_MULTI, KEY_DATE};             
 return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_DATE + "=" + deda ,
 null, null, null, null);
            }
```

Here I create a Cursor for the rows that fulfill the requirements in the last row. The String deda will be the 'dates2' we set before and I would like to get the rows where the KEY_DATE is equivalent to dates2.

The listview activity where I list the suitable rows.

```
 if (todoItems.size() > 0) {
                 todoItems.clear();  
             }
          if (list.size() > 0) {
             list.clear();   
         }
          Cursor c = info.getTable();
          c = info.getTable();
             if (c.moveToFirst())
             {
             do{
                 todoItems.add(c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2)+ " " + c.getString(3)+ " " + c.getString(4));
                                 quanitems.add(c.getString(4));
                             }
             while (c.moveToNext());
             }


             if (todoItems.size() > 0)
             {

                 for (int i=0; i<todoItems.size(); i++)
                 {

                     each=new EachRow();
                     each.text=(String) todoItems.get(i);
                     list.add(each);
                     each2=new EachRow();
                     each2.text=(String) quanitems.get(i);
                     list2.add(each2);

                 }
                 listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, 0, list)); 
             }
```

I use a custom listview, in every row there are some items, but the point is that I create a cursor (c) for the rows where the KEY_DATE is equivalent to dates2.

My problem is I never define integer variable here, but if I create an entry where the date is for example "107" or "6519684" it is working, but if it is "tableOne" or any text it crushes at the row:

```
return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_DATE + "=" + deda , null, null, null, null);
```

and

```
Cursor c = info.getTable();
```

(as you can see both problems are connected to the getTable method.

I use only Strings so practically the numbers ("107") are strings as well.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:
`return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_DATE + "=?" ,
 new String[] { deda }, null, null, null);`

Edit(explaination):

in `query` method you have  `String selection` and `String[] selectionArgs` parameters, so in `selection` you can use `?` for parameters in `selectionArgs`. Now underlying query builder will  build query with this paramater and will apply proper escape chars.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted this answer because it came earlier. However both answers are good. Could you explain why is it working?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your query should be like this:

```
return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_DATE + "= ?" ,
 new String[] {deda}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Slukian: thanks for your answer, since both answers are working I accepted Selvin's answer since it came earlier. Could you explain why is your solution working?

Comment: @JaniBela It is working because you have to enclose `Strings` in single or double quotation marks in a `SQL` query( for numeric values you don't do this). When you tried the app for `Strings` like "107", because you append directly to the `WHERE` clause the value, your query will end up like this: `KEY_DATE + "=" + deda` => `KEY_DATE + "=" + "107"` => `KEY_DATE + "=107"`, and this works.